# Validation Dependent on check box?

Tags: jquery

I have a section in my form that is only displayed if a checkbox is checked. So my validation for tho's fields should only apply if the checkbox is checked. My code does not work.

This is what i got so far and found this info on:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

```
// Validation

function validateForm() {
    $('#frmMain').validate({
        rules: {

            SuretyFullName: { required: '#chkSurety:checked' } //if required: true it works all the time.
        },
        messages: {
            SuretyFullName: { required: 'Required' }
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#btnSubmit').click();

        }
    });
}
```

Code edit: following advice: form becomes non responsive:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
if($('#chkSurety').is(":checked"))
{  
function validatesurety(){
 $('#frmMain').validate({
 rules: {       
            SuretyFullName: { required: true } 
            },
        messages: {
            SuretyFullName: { required: 'Required' } 
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validateForm() {
    $('#frmMain').validate({
        rules: {

           SuretyFullName: { required: function (element) { if ($('#chkSuretyShip').is(':checked')) { return true } else { return false} } },           
        },
        messages: {
            SuretyFullName: { required: 'Required' }
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#btnSubmit').click();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just check if it cheked an then run your function

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
 //the submit click 
      $("#submit").click(function(){
    if($('#checkboxid').is(":checked"))// check if the checkbox checked if yes 
    {
    //then call you function 
    function validateForm() ;
    }
      });
    });
```

Comment: But my validate for is for the whole form? then only if my checkbox is checked will any validation be done.

Comment: you basically running a validation function you activate it if the checkbox is checked more explanation above

Comment: I tried this but made a new function Validatesurety(), but this does not work. What does $(document) should i leave it as document or does it need to be changed to something?

Comment: I tried this even with your edit, it does not work? should i have it as $(document) or should that be changed? els my code is like that apart from my checkbox name and '#btnSubmit'... It still just validates every thing even if its not checked.

Comment: $document is like on load in this it likes prepares the function but try to get rid from submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#btnSubmit').click();

Comment: I posted the code that i have now following your advice, do you see any thing wrong because its not working?

Answer (score 2):

Put this inside your `validateForm` function:

```
// set the default rules
var rules = {
    SuretyFullName: { required: false },
    SuretyIDNumber: { required: true}, 
    SuretyPhysicalAddress: { required: true }, 
    SuretyHomeTel: { required: true}, 
    SuretyPlace: { required: true}, 
    SuretyDay: { required: true }, 
    SuretyMonth: { required: true } 
 };

 // override the full name rule, based on the checkbox
 rules.SuretyFullName.required = $('#chkSurety').is(':checked');

 $('#fmrMain').validate({
      rules: rules,
      ...
 });
```